# what's the meaning of "?" in file/folder mode bits in CentOS 6.4?

Tags: linux, centos, mount, file-permissions, sshfs

**Environment:**

2 desktops.

A is a Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS

B is a CentOS 6.4

A mounts B's folder via sshfs.

The output of 'mount' in A:

```
Lebian@zeus:/share on /mnt/share type fuse.sshfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,max_read=65536,user=Lebian)
```

**Symptom:**

If I login A with normal user, and execute 'ls' in the /mnt folder, I can get

```
drwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 4096 Oct 20  2013 share
```

But if I 'su' to root, and execute 'ls' in the /mnt folder, I will get

```
d??????????  ? ?    ?       ?            ? share
```

Is there anyone who can tell me what's the meaning of '?' and how I can fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you can't view the permissions, usually because you don't have permission on the folder itself.

Because you mounted the filesystem with `user=Lebian`, `root` can see that the mount exists, but not any information about it.

Normally `root` can access *everything*, but fuse-mounted filesystems are special; root can still access the contents with some work, but not by default.

Comment: Thank you, Could you explain more about "root can still access the contents with some work"?

Comment: easiest would be `su Lebian`, though you could also try mounting the share as `root` instead of `Lebian`.